# SharePoint CSOM Copy - RoleAssignment

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

hope you can help me out.
I'm working on a powershell script performing serveral modifications on a sharepoint environment.

I want to copy the RoleAssignments from on web to an other in the same site collection. Basicly it works when i run my commands manual in the console but it doesent work while running the script.

What I do is this.

```
    $RoleAssignmentMember =  $RoomWebRoleAssignment.Member
    $RoleBindings =  $RoomWebRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings
    $ctx.Load($RoleAssignmentMember)
    $ctx.Load($RoleBindings)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()


    $Web.RoleAssignments.Add($RoleAssignmentMember, $RoleBindings)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Running $Web.RoleAssignments.Add($RoleAssignmentMember, $RoleBindings) in console works.. not in the script .. I got an error that the collection is not ready .. but acutally it is^^..

Any Ideas ? Hope you can help
Greetz

Comment: Hi! can I ask you how are you getting $RoomWebRoleAssignment.Member and $RoomWebRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings from the first site? Thks!

Comment: I load them via the context. Something like (SpWeb is a CSOM Object of a web)

ctx.Load(spWeb, w=>w.RoleAssignments.Include(
assignment => assignment.PrincipalId,
......
) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, silly me.

for the people who are interested:

```
# Load it
$ctx.Load($Web.RoleAssignments.Add($RoleAssignmentMember, $RoleBindings));
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```